# Do hindu sects have doctrines as to whether or not other sects can provide liberation?

Tags: moksha, sects

I remember reading that Madhwas don't believe Sri-vaishnavites would achieve moksha.  I also remember reading right on this board Sri-vaishnavite theories as to how people worship other deities for many births until being born vaishnavite to achieve liberation.

Comment: Why do these arguments should bother anyone? One can simply ignore these statements and follow his/her sampradaya and do his/her Sadhana. Brahman or ultimate Truth is beyond intellect as said by Upanishads themselves. various sects tend to appear different due to limited intellect of humans but ultimately they lead us to same destination.

Comment: in the famous words of Rodney King "can't we all just get along"?  Hinduism is a very small religion not very different from hinayana Buddhism centered around nirvikalpa samadhi.  The torrent of words in vedas etc. is just a pointer - but some words point in the wrong direction and I am trying to combat that. @the destroyer

Answer (score 4):

Both pro and con opinions regarding other sects able to provide liberation are available.

Sri Ramakrishna, for example, says that all sects are paths to God.

> “With sincerity and earnestness one can realize God through all
> religions. The Vaishnavas will realize God, and so will the Saktas,
> the Vedantists, and the Brahmos. The Musalmans and Christians will
> realize Him too. All will certainly realize God if they are earnest
> and sincere.
>
> Some people indulge in quarrels, saying, ‘One cannot
> attain anything unless one worships our Krishna’, or, ‘Nothing can be
> gained without the worship of Kali, our Divine Mother’, or, ‘One
> cannot be saved without accepting the Christian religion.’ This is
> pure dogmatism. The dogmatist says, ‘My religion alone is true, and
> the religion of others are false.’ This is a bad attitude. God can be
> reached by different paths.”

The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Chapter 8, The Master's Birthday Celebration at Dakshineswar, March 11, 1883.

Certain Puranas express the exactly opposite view. Garuda Purana wages war against non Vaisnavas.

> I abhor the non Vaisnava people and  love the Vaisnava ones. I cut off
> the tongues who reproach Lord Vishnu. With the heated liquified tin I
> fill the ears of those who hear his reproaches.

Garuda Purana, Bramha (Moksha) Khanda, Chapter VI

Siva Purana is not so strident but it makes it clear that Vishnu attained his eminence because of the good wishes of Siva. Siva is Isvara and not Vishnu.

> 29. The Lord taking up a visible form in order to chastise Brahma who practised trickery, came out of the column of fire. **On seeing the
>     Lord, Vishnu stood up and with his hands shaking with fear caught hold
>     of the lord's feet.**
> 30. It is out of ignorance and delusion about you whose body is without a beginning or end that we indulged in this quest prompted by our own
>     desire. hence O, Sympathetc Being, forgive us for our fault. In fact,
>     it is but another form of your divine sport.
>
> Isvara said
>
> 31." O dear Hari, I am pleased with you, because you strictly adhered to truth in spite of your desire to be a lord. Hence among the general
> public you will have a footing equal to mine. You will be honoured too
> likewise.
>
> 32. Hereafter you will be separate from me having seaparate temple, installation of idol, festivals and worship."
> 33. Thus, formerly, the lord was delighted by the truthfulness of Hari and offered him a footing equal to his own even as the assembly of
>     devas was witnessing the same.

Siva Purana, Vidyesvarasamhita 7.29-33

Comment: I up-voted - but you are answer depicts the flip side - Hindu universalism as opposed to sectarianism.

Comment: Yes, such an attitude is also expressed in Gita 4.11. However just because all spiritual systems are accepted as paths, inspite of their many errors, do not mean Hindus should practice other paths.

Comment: not practicing someone elses's sect is fine, but examples of explicitly declaring :sect X alone will lead to liberation, or sect y will not lead to liberation is what I am looking for.

Comment: Your question is worded to mean the exact opposite of what you have stated in your comment. You should have asked the question, 'Do Hindu sects have doctrines as to other sects not being able to provide liberation.'. It seems I misunderstood your question.  Puranas have declarations that declare war against other sects.

Comment: Yes, and I have expanded my answer.

Comment: I am not asking for general sectarian mud-slinging - specifically whether sect A thinks sect B can/cannot lead to liberation.  I can understand chasms like saiva/vaishnava but it would be surprising if Madhwas say srivaishnavites will not get liberation.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay I don't think the  garuda purana is waging war against non vaishnavas.